# Java Grading Program: For-Loop Freezing or Working Improperly Issue

Tags: java, for-loop

```
if(numGrade[1] >= 100)
{
    System.out.println("Your English grade is perfect! Keep it up!");
}

else if(numGrade[1] < 90 && numGrade[1] > 80)
{
    for(;testGrade >= 90; testPossible[1]++, testGet[1]++)
    {
        if(testGet[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testGet[1]");
            if(testPossible[1] == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(testPossible[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            testGrade[1] = testGet[1]/testPossible[1];
        }
    }
    testTheory[1] = pointsGet[1] - testGet[1];
    System.out.println(testTheory[1] + " points needed to get an A in English!");
}

else if(numGrade[1] < 80 && numGrade[1] > 70)
{
    for(;testGrade[1] >= 80; testPossible[1]++, testGet[1]++)
    {
        if(testGet[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testGet[1]");
            if(testPossible[1] == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(testPossible[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            testGrade[1] = testGet[1]/testPossible[1];
        }
    }
    testTheory[1] = pointsGet[1] - testGet[1];
    System.out.println(testTheory[1] + " points needed to get a B in English!");
}

else if(numGrade[1] < 70 && numGrade[1] > 60)
{
    for(;testGrade[1] >= 70; testPossible[1]++, testGet[1]++)
    {
        if(testGet[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testGet[1]");
            if(testPossible[1] == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(testPossible[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            testGrade[1] = testGet[1]/testPossible[1];
        }
    }
    testTheory[1] = pointsGet[1] - testGet[1];
    System.out.println(testTheory[1] + " points needed to get a C in English!");
}

else if(numGrade[1] < 50)
{
    for(;testGrade[1] >= 60; testPossible[1]++, testGet[1]++)
    {
        if(testGet[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testGet[1]");
            if(testPossible[1] == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
                System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(testPossible[1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Illegal division value for testPossible[1]");
            System.out.println("SYSTEM: Exiting program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            testGrade[1] = testGet[1]/testPossible[1];
        }
    }
    testTheory[1] = pointsGet[1] - testGet[1];
    System.out.println(testTheory[1] + " points needed to get a D in English!");
}
else if(numGrade[1] < 0)
{
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: Could not show numGrade[1]");
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: Negative grade value for numGrade[1]");
}

else if(numGrade[1] == 0)
{
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: Could not show numGrade[1]");
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: No grade value for numGrade[1]");
}

else
{
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: Could not show numGrade[1]");
    System.out.println("SYSTEM: Unknown cause");
}
System.exit(0);
```

Whenever I try to run this, I either get "You need 0 points to get a B" or, when I try to edit anything really (The variable position, the Boolean operators, etc.) the compiler I'm using freezes. I don't know if this matters, but I am using the Pico Compiler app on my iPad to run this. Works as intended when I comment the for loop out (No surprise). No errors ever show.

Comment: Reduce the code to relevant parts and explain what part goes wrong.

Comment: Haven't you done arrays yet? Working with variables like that is... unadvised.

Comment: @Gaël Done. No errors, but console is flooded with errors when I attempt to run it. None of the errors point to any location in the file. They all seem to point to CodeHaus (?)

Comment: Provide the errors then

Comment: @Gaël imageupload.co.uk/image/cebd

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to begin reducing the size of your code using the `array` concept mentioned by @RealSkeptic (and a `for` loop):

```
  double[] numGrade       = { 79,  75,  78, 100,  70,  78};
  double[] pointsPossible ;
  double[] pointsGet ;
  String[] gpa;

  for (int i = 0; i < numGrade.length; i++) {
    pointsGet[i]      = numGrade[i];
    pointsPossible[i] = 100;
    gpa[i]            = "A";
  }
```

Where you go from there is another matter, but the code you supplied isn't what you want to live with. You should Google `java arrays` or consult text; this is just to get you started. Hope it helps without being overly confusing.

(By the way, this makes `pointsGet` identical to `numGrade`; you may want to alter the code if you really want `hourFourPointsGet` to be 100.)

Comment: Well, the problem mainly is that I don't intend to keep having to change the grade values, as I want to make it be read by the JDK scanner. I have the test variables so I don't alter the actual grade variable's values. I am trying to sort of make a duplicate of the variable, so I can change the values of it to have in the for loop for testing how many points I need to get a (insert letter grade here), and not have the actual grade values affected. Problem is, from what I can tell, it happens anyways.